# JSP <jsp:include /> vs <%@ include %> when concatenating with a variable

Tags: eclipse, jsp, netbeans

I am new to Java and JSP.  I am trying to use eclipse Mars.1 to create a JSP application to see how it compares to using NetBeans 8 IDE.

In NetBeans 8 the following worked to include a file where "action" holds the name of the desired file.

```
  <jsp:include page="<%= "/views/"+session.getAttribute("action")+".jsp" %>"/>
```

In eclipse Mars.1 this same line gives this error in the browser.

```
  (line: 16, column: 25) Attribute value "/views/" + session.getAttribute("action") + ".jsp" is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
```

To solve this issue I attempted to use

```
 <%@ include file="/views/" + ${sessionScope.action} + ".jsp" %>
```

I found out some information that using the JSP EL the `+` is always a math function.

How would I accomplish using the variable `sessionScope.action` to build a string for the file attribute?

Comment: <%@include %> is a **static** include, that is resolved when the container transforms the JSP into a servlet. It can't contain dynamic expressions.

Comment: Thanks JB.  I have tried a number of variations to fix the error that appears to be about the quotes.  Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Found the solution.  The error is a tomcat issue so I used a single quote around the value for page.